# Randomize array content in PHP via Wordpress posts

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, random, posts

Do you guys know how to limit posts per page and randomize posts in wordpress?

I have a relationship field in the back-end where I add and remove items that I created to display in a website. This content is printed through the WP_Query below:

```
<?php
  $args = array (
    'post_type'      => 'home_banners'

  $fullbanner = new WP_Query ( $args );
?>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $fullbanner->have_posts() ) : $fullbanner->the_post(); ?>

#####Get the relationship field
<?php $banners = get_field('home_banner_01_selection'); ?>
#####Check if the relationship field has contents
<?php if( $banners ): ?>
  #####Start foreach
  <?php foreach( $banners as $banner ): ?>
    <a href="<?php the_field('home_link', $banner->ID ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'home_headline', $banner->ID ); ?></a>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I have three contents added in this relationship field. I want just to display ONLY ONE content per page and randomize it when refreshing the page. At the moment it is currently display all the three contents in the page.

I notice that the var `$banners` behave as an `array`. If I add `echo count($banners);` it will display 3. Moreover, if I add `shuffle($banners);` it will shuffle the content among them.

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could shuffle the array $banners and then just echo out the post in array wit

```
<?php
    $banners = get_field('home_banner_01_selection');
    if($banners) {
        shuffle($banners);
        ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('home_link', $banners[0]->ID ); ?>"><?php the_field( 'home_headline', $banners[0]->ID ); ?></a>
        <?php
    }
?>
```